# Referencing, am trying to reference two articles that I haven't read inside of an article that I have read

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, natbib, multiple-citations

Hello I am trying to reference two articles that I haven't read that are cited in an article that I have read using the macros of the `natbib` citation management package:

```
\citep{tenopir_electronic_2009, tenopir_variations_2009, tenopir_beyond_2011}
```

This gives me the following output:

> (Tenopir et al., 2009a,b; Tenopir, 2011).

so I am trying to cite the first two which are in the last reference. But I need to add 'cited in' inside of the \citep command so that the output will be

> (Tenopir et al., 2009a,b; cited in Tenopir, 2011).

Any help please

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The following may be more a question about content instead about LaTeX/BibTeX coding practice: Is what what you really want to say "[some claim] (Tenopir et al., 2009a,b; as quoted in Tenopir, 2011)", rather than "[some claim] (Tenopir et al., 2009a,b; as cited in Tenopir, 2011)"? Please advise.

Comment: Yes the first option in your comment is what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to achieve your formatting objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{smith:09a, author = {A. Smith}, title = {Thoughts {I}},   year = 2009}
@misc{smith:09b, author = {A. Smith}, title = {Thoughts {II}},  year = 2009}
@misc{smith:11,  author = {A. Smith}, title = {Thoughts {III}}, year = 2011}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round,notesep={; }}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\begin{document}

(\citealp{smith:09a,smith:09b}; as quoted in \citealp{smith:11})

\citep[as quoted in \citealp{smith:11}]{smith:09a,smith:09b}

\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```